# midnight commander : how to invoke drop down on directory history list

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, midnight-commander

I use mc 4.1.36 (C) ported to windows(I use Vista). I would love to be able to navigate through the list of directories that I've previously visited using the drop-down except that I don't know how to invoke it. This version of mc i use does not have support for mouse. So, what is the KEY that will invoke this drop-down behavior ? Years ago, by accident, I invoked it but I forgot to document it.

Comment: If you like text-mode file managers for Windows, a far more capable one than MC (which I love and use on Linux), is [NDN](http://ndn.muxe.com). Plenty of shortcuts, and they just work, out of the box.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the Midnight Commander docs in the [default shortcuts for file panel actions](https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/common/actions#Filepanelactions):

```
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| History      | Alt-H  | show the directory history       |
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| HistoryNext  | Alt-u  | move to the next directory       |
|              |        | in the history                   |
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------+
| HistoryPrev  | Alt-y  | move to the previous directory   |
|              |        | in the history                   |
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> in this case is an abbreviation of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>