# "ALT" key not working in Midnight Commander on macOS terminal

Tags: macos, midnight-commander

I frequently use the [history drop down](https://superuser.com/questions/200565/) in Midnight Commander on Linux via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, and it doesn't work. In fact, none of the commands that require <kbd>Alt</kbd> do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to solve this:

- **Adjust the terminal settings**

  Quoting from [this post](https://www.shell-tips.com/mac/meta-key):

  > The domain for the Terminal app is `com.apple.Terminal`. You will need to look for your default Window Setting with the key `Default Window Settings`. Then, based of this, look at the corresponding nested dictionary inside the dictionnary `Window Settings` and set the key `useOptionAsMetaKey` to `1`.
  >
  > Alternatively, instead of using `defaults` in the command line, you can simply go to the `Terminal` > `Preferences...` (or type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>). Then, `Profiles` > `Keyboard` and check the box `Use Option as Meta key`. Though, this wouldn’t be as fun.
- **Switch to using the other default Meta key: <kbd>Esc</kbd>**

  According the Midnight Commander documentation's [Actions and default shortcuts](https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/common/actions) section:

  > Meta - "Alternate" key, or "Alt", or "Meta", also can be replaced with a single "Esc" or "Escape";

  That is, keyboard combinations that require <kbd>Alt</kbd> will become a **sequence** of combos:

  1. The first "combo" is <kbd>Esc</kbd>: press and release quickly.
  2. The second combo is the rest. (In this case, it will be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.)